# How to shorten the code to convert information word to hamming code in MARIE

Tags: marie

I have made a MARIE code that takes the input of 8 information bits and converts it to 12-bit hamming code. How to shorten this code? I am using the same XOR function for each parity bit with different value of each bit.
I have first taken input for 8  bits in a loop and stored it at different addresses like an array. Then, I found the XOR of different parity bits (knowing the positions beforehand) and substituted the parity bits in the main information word (using the addresses of each position). Finally gave an output of the hamming code.

I have posted the code below:

'''

```
ORG 100

getInput,   LoadI data
            Skipcond 000
            Input
            Store temp
            LoadI data
            Skipcond 000
            Load temp
            StoreI data
            Load data
            Add one
            Store data
            Clear
            Load size
            Subt one
            Store size
            Skipcond 400
            Jump getInput
            
Load dataTop
Add two
Store data
Load sizeMax
Store size

p1loop, LoadI data
        Add p1
        Store p1
        Load data
        Add two
        Store data
        Load size
        Subt two
        Store size
        Skipcond 400
        Jump p1loop

XOR,    Load p1
        Subt two
        Store p1
        Skipcond 000
        Jump XOR

Add two
Store p1     
Load dataTop
Store data
Load p1
StoreI data

Load dataTop
Add two
Store data
LoadI data
Store p2
Load sizeMax
Subt 2
Store size

p2loop, Load data
        Add three
        Store data
        LoadI data
        Add p2
        Store p2
        Load data
        Add one
        Store data
        LoadI data
        Add p2
        Store p2
        Load size
        Subt four
        Store size
        Skipcond 400
        Jump p2loop 

XOR2,   Load p2
        Subt two
        Store p2
        Skipcond 000
        Jump XOR2

Add two
Store p2
Load dataTop
Add one
Store data
Load p2
StoreI data

Load dataTop
Add four
Store data
Load three
Store size

p3loop, LoadI data
        Add p3
        Store p3
        Load data
        Add one
        Store data
        Load size
        Subt one
        Store size
        Skipcond 400
        Jump p3loop

Load dataTop
Add eleven
Store data
LoadI data
Add p3
Store p3

XOR3,   Load p3
        Subt two
        Store p3
        Skipcond 000
        Jump XOR3

Add two
Store p3    
Load dataTop
Add three
Store data
Load p3
StoreI data

Load dataTop
Add eight
Store data
Load eight
Store size

p4loop, LoadI data
        Add p4
        Store p4
        Load data
        Add one
        Store data
        Load size
        Subt one
        Store size
        Skipcond 400
        Jump p4loop

XOR4,   Load p4
        Subt two
        Store p4
        Skipcond 000
        Jump XOR4

Add two
Store p4   
Load dataTop
Add seven
Store data
Load p4
StoreI data

Load dataTop
Store data
Load sizeMax
Store size
    
ShowOutput, Clear
            LoadI data
            Output
            Load data
            Add one
            Store data
            Clear
            Load size
            Subt one
            Store size
            Skipcond 400
            Jump ShowOutput
            Halt
    
one, DEC 1
two, DEC 2
three, DEC 3
four, DEC 4
seven, DEC 7
eight, DEC 8
eleven, DEC 11
p1, DEC 0
p2, DEC 0
p3, DEC 0
p4, DEC 0
sizeMax, DEC 12
size, DEC 12
dataTop, HEX 1B0
temp, DEC  0
data, HEX 1B0
    DEC -1
    DEC -1
    DEC 1
    DEC -1
    DEC 1
    DEC 1
    DEC 1
    DEC -1
    DEC 1
    DEC 1
    DEC 1
    DEC 1
```

'''

Comment: Seems to me that you're looking for algorithmic improvements, so, why don't you share the C version of this algorithm so we can digest it faster?

Comment: I don't code in C language and have made my code directly in MARIE. Should I remake this code in java and send it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some small points:

```
XOR4,   Load p4
        Subt two
        Store p4
        Skipcond 000
        Jump XOR4

Add two
Store p4
```

Don't need to both load & store p4 inside the loop, so this would also work:

```
Load p4
XOR4,   
        Subt two
        Skipcond 000
        Jump XOR4

Add two
Store p4
```

---

For another point, you don't really need p2 through p4, because when the code is done with `p1`, it never uses it again, instead switching to `p2`, finishes with that then moves on to `p3`.  The only benefit of having p2 through p4 is that they are initialized to 0.  So, the code could use just p1 everywhere as long as it is cleared before looping.

I mention that because one approach to making the code smaller is to share the same code for all 4 looping operations.  That would require some abstraction, and removing the unnecessary variables can help with that.

Otherwise, most of the various loops read the same except for the constants they use.  So, perhaps put the constants in a table, and then an outer loop of around the shared code so it runs 4 times, using different constants from the table.

The 4 loops do have some other differences, and perhaps those differences could also be selected from the table or perhaps by testing the outer loop variable, within some if-then type constructs in the inner loop.

Comment: Yes, I could make the XOR part smaller as you said, and the 4 loops are a bit different as they are made for different positions of parity bits. Thanks for the help.